# Can't find Vue component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm starting to learn vue. Today I had tried to use Typescript with Vue, so I need to configure webpack in order to make it posible. I'm using Webstrom and in the Typescript console it says me that it can't find Vue module. I have build the project and everything appears to be good, so I don't know if this error is from the Typescript console.

Here is the two files involved in this error

**Main.ts**

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import TestComponent from "./components/Test.vue";

let v = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  template: `
    <div class="div">
        Name: <input v-model="name" type="text">
        <test-component :name="name" :bas="4"/>
    </div>
 `,
  data: {
    name: "World"
  },
  components: {
    TestComponent
  }
});
```

**Test.Vue**

```html
<template>
        <div class="div">
            <div class="test">Testing {{name}}</div>
            <button @click="testB"></button>
        </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
   import Vue from "vue";

   export default Vue.extend({
     props: ['name', 'bas'],
     data() {
       return {
         a: this.bas
       }
     },
     methods: {
       testB() {
         this.a++;
       }
     },
   });
</script>

<style>
    .test{
        font-size: 24px;
     }
</style>
```

In this repo you can see the code of the project [repo](https://github.com/Acelator/Study-helper/tree/master/frontend)

Comment: What's the exact error?

Comment: Where are you using typescript?

Comment: I don't know what do you refer to? I compiled main.ts and then It creates a .js file and then I link this file in my Html

Comment: The error is TS2307